# show hide field based on radio button selection in new form

Tags: jquery

I have a field "Manager" (radio button with value yes and no) and another field country(dropdpwn)
If I select manager = yes then only country should display else it should be hidden when user go to new form.

Below is my code, please let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
$("select[title='Manager]").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='Geographical span']").val() == "Yes")
{
$('nobr:contains("Country")').closest('tr').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use SPUtility.js to **Hide/Show** SharePoint list fields.

**Updated Code:**

```
$("select[title='Manager]").change(function() {         
if (SPUtility.GetSPField("Geographical span").GetValue() == "No"){              
    SPUtility.GetSPField("Country").Hide();
}
else{
    SPUtility.GetSPField("Country").Show();
}
});
```

**Source for SPUtility.js :** https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility/blob/master/src/sputility.js

**Note :** You have to include reference for **SPUtility.js** file in your code.